# Target a parent window

Tags: javascript, html

If you open a new window, or a new tab in the case of newer browsers, using the target attibute of _blank, in the new window is it possible to target links to open in the original "parent" window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use a popup window, which can refer to its parent using `window.opener`. I am not entirely certain, but this might also work for windows opened using a `_blank` target.

Turns out it is possible. Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/CftQr/show/

Follow the link to open the child window in a new tab, then use the link on the child page to redirect the parent to [google.com](http://google.com).

Comment: Nice one. So simple. Thanks.

Comment: This might not be working because of the modern browser policy.